# Check whether a JPanel contains a JButton

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, jcomponent

I have added a button to a `JPanel`. I want to remove the button if the `JPanel` contains the button.  Is there any way to check whether the `JPanel` contains the button?

Comment: what's wrong with looping through the panel's children?

Answer (score 10):

If you have a reference to the `JButton`, call [getParent()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getParent%28%29).  If the parent is `null`, the button is not in the panel (or any container).

Alternately, do as @kleopatra suggested and call [getComponents()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponents%28%29) on the `JPanel` instance and iterate the array looking for anything that is an `instanceof JButton`.

Answer (score 7):

Is checking necessary? If not, then just remove the `JButton` without checking. Nothing will happen if it is not contained by the `JPanel`.

Comment: The question is: 'how can I check whether a JPanel contains a JButton?'. People that search for that question will be referred to this answer. This answer is good advice for the asker's particular purpose, but not an adequate answer to the general question.

Comment: @Maarten: You are right. I answered the question description, not the title but people are usually interested about the title. I think [Andrew's Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7318993/887149) bellow is good for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a reference to the button:

```
List<Component> componentList = Arrays.asList(panel.getComponents());
if (!componentList.contains(button)) {
  panel.add(button);
}
```